# Pasar variables de PHP a una función

Tags: ajax

Buen día,

Tengo un formulario novedad.php que maneja AJAX y funciones, este formulario carga un archivo PHP llamada ListaDescuento.php que tiene la opción de eliminar y modificar, al dar clic en editar envía unos parámetros a una función que está en el archivo novedad.php, el inconveniente es cuando envío datos de tipo texto, el formulario en AJAX no se visualiza, pero si envío un número si se visualiza.

A continuación relaciono parte del código fuente:

novedad.php (Código de la función)

```html
 function addDescuento(ID_Novedad,Documento,Ano,Mes,periodo,Concepto) {
   
      $('#nuevoDescuento').load('ll_tbdescuentonew.php?ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad+ '&Documento='+ Documento + '&Ano='+ Ano + '&Mes='+ Mes + '&periodo='+ periodo + '&Concepto='+ Concepto);
  }
```

ListaDescuento.php

```html
echo '<td align="left"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Editar Descuento" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar" onclick="editarDescuento('.$fila[0].','.$fila[2].')"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>';
```

Si cambio $fila[2] y coloco cualquier otro registro que sea númerico, el programa me visualiza el formulario.

Quedaría muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar con este inconveniente.

Comment: Hola Juan, Me puedes apoyar que tienes en este archivo "ll_tbdescuentonew.php"

Comment: Hola gama, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, ya encontré la solución, y fue de la siguiente manera    echo '<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="ID_Novedad" id="ID_Novedad" placeholder="No hay datos con los filtros seleccionados" size="50" value ='.$fila[1].' readonly required="true">';
            echo '<td align="left"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Editar Descuento" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar" onclick="editarDescuento('.$fila[0].',ID_Novedad.value)"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>';

Answer (score 0):

Trata esto:
Modifique el código con lo que me mandaste, esto te debe funcionar

```
      function lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Novedad,Documento,Ano,Mes,periodo,Concepto){

      var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
      var Documento = $('#Docu').val();
      var Ano = $('#Anoen').val();
      var Mes = $('#Mesen').val();
      var periodo = $('#Peri').val();
      var Concepto = $('#Conce').val();
    //var datastring ={'ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad + '&Documento=' + Documento + '&Ano=' + Ano + '&Mes=' + Mes + '&periodo=' + periodo + '&Concepto=' + Concepto};
          $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "lista_DescuentoNovedad.php",
            data: 'D_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad+ '&Documento='+ Documento + '&Ano='+ Ano + '&Mes='+ Mes + '&periodo='+ periodo + '&Concepto='+ Concepto,
            success: function(x){
              $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
        /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/      
                $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
             }, 
             beforeSend: function(){
                $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html('<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
              },
               error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){}
           });

 }
```

Creo que estas mandado mal el ajax, tienes que revisar bien el concepto de load y ajax .

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero me genera Undefined index, el código es el siguiente:

Answer (score 0):

Código de la función:

```html
 function lista_DescuentoNovedad(ID_Novedad,Documento,Ano,Mes,periodo,Concepto){
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var ID_Novedad = $('#ID_Nova').val();
  var Documento = $('#Docu').val();
  var Ano = $('#Anoen').val();
  var Mes = $('#Mesen').val();
  var periodo = $('#Peri').val();
  var Concepto = $('#Conce').val();
  var datastring ={'ID_Novedad=' + ID_Novedad + '&Documento=' + Documento + '&Ano=' + Ano + '&Mes=' + Mes + '&periodo=' + periodo + '&Concepto=' + Concepto};
          $.ajax({
          beforeSend: function(){
             $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html('<b>Actualizando lista de Descuentos en la novedad...</b>');
           },
          url: 'lista_DescuentoNovedad.php',
    data: datastring,
          type: 'POST',
          success: function(x){
            $("#lista_DescuentoNovedad").html(x);
   /********************HAY QUE VALIDAR #lista_clientes*******************************/
            $("#lista_clientes").dataTable();
           },
           error: function(jqXHR,estado,error){}
           });
          });
 }
```

Código del lista_DescuentoNovedad.php

```html
<?php
include ("funciones/conex.php");
$link=Conectarse();

$ID_Novedad = $_POST['ID_Novedad'];
$Documento = $_POST['Documento'];
$Ano = $_POST['Ano'];
$Mes = $_POST['Mes'];
$periodo = $_POST['periodo'];
$Concepto = $_POST['Concepto'];
$AnoActual=date("Y");
$con=mysql_query("SELECT D.ID,D.ID_Novedad,D.ID_Dcto,D.ValorDcto,D.Estado,DC.NomDcto FROM tbl_dtldcto as D INNER JOIN tbl_dctos AS DC ON D.ID_Dcto=DC.ID_Dcto where D.ID_Novedad='$ID_Novedad' AND D.Estado = 'PENDIENTE'",$link);

?>
```

De antemano gracias por tu ayuda y si me puedes colaborar te quedaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Hola @Juan Carlos, si esto es parte de tu pregunta no debería ir aquí en la zona de respuestas, por favor edita tu pub. original y ahi agrega lo que falte

Comment: Hola Gracias por la aclaración, es que soy nuevo en esta comunidad.